# Turn the section font from bold to roman in a table of contents

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, titletoc

I have some trouble using the `titletoc` package to edit a simple ToC composed only of several sections. I would just like to turn their font from **bold** (which is the default font) to roman, but I am definitely making some mistake with the `\titlecontents` command. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\usepackage[tiny]{titlesec}

\usepackage{titletoc}
% \titlecontents ???

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section[Reference A]{\fullcite{bibtexkey A}}
\section[Reference B]{\fullcite{bibtexkey B}}
\section[Reference C]{\fullcite{bibtexkey C}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify the font in the `\titlecontents` command:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,titletoc}

\titlecontents{section} % set formatting for \section -
                        % \subsection must be formatted separately 
[2.3em]                 % adjust left margin
{\rmfamily}             % font formatting
{\contentslabel{2.3em}} % section label and offset
{\hspace*{-2.3em}}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Joe}
\lipsum

\section{Blow}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

which gives you:

[image]

`titlesec` and `titletoc` are nice but getting the arguments right is a bit challenging, a key-value interface would be easier.

Comment: Thank you Micheal. If you could add the details Werner mentions, that would be great.

Comment: oops - fixed according to Werner's suggestion. Notice the multiple instances of the 2.3em length parameter. These interact with one another; just change them around a bit and observe what happens, it's easier to observe in action than to explain. (It seems I deleted Werner's comment - that was unintentional. Sorry.)